# How to configure to sidekiq queue to run only task at a time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process, sidekiq

I am using Sidekiq in my Rails application to process background jobs.

sidekiq.yml

```
:verbose: false
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
:concurrency: 5
:queues:
  - ["queue1", 1]
  - ["queue2", 1]
  - ["queue3", 1]
  - ["queue4", 1]
  - ["queue5", 1]
  - critical
  - default
  - low
max_retries: 1
```

I want to run one only task per queue at a time.

For example: I am starting same worker 3 times in queue1, I want to process the worker1 and then worker2 and then worker3.

I have added "1" with queue name (e.g ["queue1", 1]) in sidekiq.yml. I thought this configuration will run only one worker in queue1. But that is not happening.

How to achieve the above configuration in sidekiq?

Comment: It's not clear. You want your 3 workers to pick jobs from queue1 in a round-robin fashion (one works, the other two wait)? Or worker1 works on queue1, worker2 works on queue2 and so on?

Comment: I mean  like round-robin fashion. one works, the other two wait

Comment: @karan In that case why dont you just set 1 worker per queue?

Comment: @MartinZinovsky It will not be good in my case. I have more number of workers. I want to limit the workers per queue.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Any help would be appreciated

Comment: May I ask, why do you need multiple workers when you make them wait?

Comment: Each worker is writing different data to S3. I don't want to same data at same time.

Comment: @Galet can't you give the scope of data wich each worker should handle by the job invoking time(as an argumet to perform_later)?

Answer (score 3):

First a slight correction in the terminologies. "Workers" are constantly running threads that consume "jobs" from "queues". Hence you don't process worker1, instead worker1 will process jobs from queue1.

Now coming to the solution:-

It seems that your use case is that you don't want specific type of job (one that uploads to s3 in your case) to be executed on more than one worker at a given instant.

To achieve that, you will need a locking mechanism at job level. Sidekiq doesn't provide locking on its own, hence you need to use external gems for that.

I have used redis based 'sidekiq-lock' to achieve something similar in my projects.

[Gem Link](https://github.com/emq/sidekiq-lock)

Usage is as follows:-

```
class Worker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidekiq::Lock::Worker

  # static lock that expires after one second
  sidekiq_options lock: { timeout: 1000, name: 'unique-lock-name' }

  def perform
    # your code to upload to s3
  end
end
```

This will ensure that your code is running only one instance of given job on one worker at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the built in [ActiveJob](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) because it sounds like you want FIFO queue. Sidekiq is for idempotent concurrent backgrounding

Comment: yes either you have a bad design in the first place and now paying technical debts or you are using the wrong tool for the job. maybe RabbitMQ may suit you.

Answer (score 1):

I think [it](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#workers) that you want a [feature](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#workers)

Add it to your worker class

```
class YourWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :queue1
```

But there are a caveat which worker only could queueing by queue1.

Comment: This does exactly what was wanted! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sidekiq explicitly does not allow what you want to do.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#3-embrace-concurrency

Answer (score 0):

`queues` setting controls how often queue will be checked for jobs to control it's priority related to others, not limiting parallel jobs to that queue.

Also you can spin up multiple workers with limited number of threads (that's what sidekiq documentation suggests for this case), but this may not be practical for many queues with low load, when most of the workers will idle.

To limit particular queue parallel jobs within one worker - you can use gem [sidekiq-limit_fetch](https://github.com/brainopia/sidekiq-limit_fetch) and settings like:

```
:limits:
  queue1: 1
  queue2: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sidekiq-limit_fetch](https://github.com/brainopia/sidekiq-limit_fetch) to use advanced options for sidekiq. To limit concurrency on individual queue, you can do the following.

Step 1. Add `gem 'sidekiq-limit_fetch'` in your Gemfile

Step 2. Add limits for each queue in your sidekiq.yml

`:limits:
    queue1: 1
    queue2: 1
    queue3: 1
    queue4: 1`

Answer (score -1):

[Set your Sidekiq concurrency](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#concurrency) to 1. This way you'll have only 1 thread working in your process which would give you the desired output: only 1 job is done at a time.

Just change your configuration file:

```
:verbose: false
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
:concurrency: 1 # Change Here
:queues:
  - ["queue1", 1]
  - ["queue2", 1]
  - ["queue3", 1]
  - ["queue4", 1]
  - ["queue5", 1]
  - critical
  - default
  - low
max_retries: 1
```